# Keeping only specific sentences from a string in python

Tags: python

I have a large string with natural text in it.

Now I want to write a code that will only print sentences from that string that contain the word "but".
Normally I would write something like this:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
file1 = open ( 'text.txt', 'r' )
str1 = file1.read()
sent=sent_tokenize(str1)
word=word_tokenize(str1)
but=["but"]
for w in word:
   if w in but:
      print sent
```

but this will ofcourse not work as the sentence is no longer retained, everyone have any idead?
I thus do not just need the word "but" x number of times, I need the sentences it occurs in.

Thanks

Comment: Load all lines into a list and check if line contains "but".

Answer (score 2):

```
file1 = open ( 'text.txt', 'r' )
str1 = file1.read()
sent = sent_tokenize(str1)
for s in sent:
   if 'but' in s:
      print s
```

Will this code not work?

Comment: yes! it works like a charm, thank you so much. The answer is always so obvios when I finally see it.